# Non greedy regular expression not matching what I expected

Tags: regex, non-greedy

I am searching through text for lines which use "variable2" without a semicolon before it in the line. Here is my regular expression to solve this.

`^[^;]*?variable2`

My understanding of this is that it should find text starting with a newline which minimizes the number of non semicolon characters followed by "variable2".
This fails to select what I expect in this example.

```
Label0: mov     variable0,WREG             ;Some comment
        mov     W0,variable1

Label1: btsc    variable2,#1               ;Some other comment
        bra     label2
```

I expected to get this

```
Label1: btsc    variable2
```

but selected this instead

```
        mov     W0,variable1

Label1: btsc    variable2
```

What am I misunderstanding? It seems to me the non-greedy expression is not doing what I intended it to do. If I change my regular expression to `^[^;\n]*?variable2`, it selects what I expect it to select. I am using Sublime Text 2 for my regular expressions, but I seem to get the same results in php, javascript, and python (according to regex101.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting a key point of lazy matching incorrect here: It doesn't try to find the overall shortest possible match, but it tries to find the shortest possible match from the beginning. Let's take a much shorter regex to show this: `a*?b`. Given a string `aab`, you are expecting the lazy match to match `ab`, but it matches `aab`.

The regex parser starts with the first character in the string (the first `a`) and matches it lazy. It then continues, but fails to match `b` as the second character is still an `a`. It then expands the `a*?` pattern to match `aa` and now can successfully match `b`, giving the overall match `aab`.

Comment: Yes, I thought it would actively look for a shorter set of characters to match. I have always called it non-greedy, but lazy is a much more descriptive word for it.

Answer (score 2):

`^[^;]*?variable2`

This regex matches anything other than `;` from the start of the line till `variable2`.Since line 2 and line 3(just a newline) also don't contain any `;` they are matched starting from the beginning of the 2nd line till `variable2`. Since you are using multiline mode, `^` acts as an anchor for each line.

[Demo](http://regexr.com/3diaq)

`^[^;\n]*?variable2`

This regex matches anything other than `;` and `\n` from the start of the line till variable2. Line 2 and line 3 are not matched since they contain `\n`.

[Demo](http://regexr.com/3diat)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a **negative lookahead**:

```
^(?:(?!;).)+variable2
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/qO1pP8/2) (and mind the `multiline` modifier!).

```
^           # matches the beginning of the line
(?:(?!;).)+ # match any character except a newline
            # and make sure what immediately follows
            # is not a semicolon 
variable2   # match variable2
```